# Expand space between data points in ggforestplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, r-forestplot

Im using the `ggforestplot`package to create a forest plot with 20 risk factors and 7 outcomes.

For that im using this code

```
df <-
  df_logodds_associations %>%
  # Set the study variable to a factor to preserve order of appearance
  mutate(
    study = factor(
      study,
      levels = c("Meta-analysis", "NFBC-1997", "DILGOM", "FINRISK-1997", "YFS")
    )
  ) %>%

# Draw a forestplot of odds ratios
ggforestplot::forestplot(
  df = df,
  name = name,
  estimate = beta,
  se = se,
  pvalue = pvalue,
  psignif = 0.002,
  colour = study,
  shape = study,
  xlab = "Odds ratio for incident type 2 diabetes (95% CI)\nper 1−SD increment in metabolite concentration",
  title = "Amino acids",
  logodds = TRUE
) +
  ggplot2::scale_shape_manual(
    values = c(23L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L),
    labels = c("Meta-analysis", "NFBC-1997", "DILGOM", "FINRISK-1997", "YFS")
  )
#> Scale for 'shape' is already present. Adding another scale for 'shape', which
#> will replace the existing scale.
```

This code is directly from the [`vignette`](https://nightingalehealth.github.io/ggforestplot/articles/ggforestplot.html).

But using seven instead of five outcomes gives me this picture.

[image]

Is there any way to expand the space between the datapoints to make it visually possible to distinguish the data?

Comment: You need to make the plot taller by stretching your plotting window. If your plot size is fixed, there is simply no room in your image to increase the spacing.

Comment: I have tried that by using dev.new but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: When your graphics device renders the plot to your screen it will adjust the elements based on the available size of the window. For example, if you are in Rstudio - you can resize the 'plots' pane or zoom that window and you'll see the plot re-render. If you are outputting to a raster file (e.g. `.png`) then you can specify the dimensions.